# MongoDB group by embedded document structure

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to know if I can do the following in MongoDB. Suppose we have this collection

```
[{
  timestamp: 1,
  account: 'A',
  features: {
    amount: 24,
    velocity: 6.4
  }
},
{
  timestamp: 2,
  account: 'B',
  features: {
    amount: 64,
    velocity: 4.6
  }
},
{
  timestamp: 3,
  account: 'C',
  features: {
    amount: 75,
    velocity: 1.4,
    latitude: 3.54,
    longitude: -1.65
  }
}]
```

I would like to know if it's possible to group the documents above by the structure of the embedded document 'features'. The first two documents should be grouped together since the embedded document has the same structure and the third should be grouped on its own since the embedded document has a different structure to the first two. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to achieve this in an [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) performed on the collection.

You start out projecting all fields for the embedded `features` document.

**Stage 1**: Convert embedded `features` document to [array of key value pairs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) and project in a new field.

```
{ 
  $project: {
    "timestamp": 1,
    "account": 1,
    "features": 1,
    "features_array": { $objectToArray: "$features" } 
   } 
}
```

**Stage 2**: Get keys in the array and project in a new field

```
{
  $project: { 
    "feature_keys": "$features_array.k" 
  }
}
```

**Stage 3**: Then, you can [group by](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) new '`feature_keys`' field added in the documents in the first aggregation stage.

```
{
   $group: {"_id": "$feature_keys", "feature_things": { $push: "$$ROOT" }}
}
```

This stages can be performed on the collection to yield grouped results of documents by feature keys.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    <Stage 1>,
    <Stage 2>,
    <Stage 3>,
])
```

---

*EDIT ADD as per the comments below:*

I think the result from this query gives the grouping (this is some refinement with @Oluwafemi Sule's answer).This can be run with the data from the question post:

```
db.test.aggregate ([
 {
    $project: { 
        "timestamp": 1,    
        "account": 1,
        "features": 1,
        "features_array": { $objectToArray: "$features" }
    } 
  },
 {
    $addFields: {
      "feature_keys": "$features_array.k"
    } 
  },
  {
    $group: { 
         "_id": "$feature_keys",
         "feature_things": { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    } 
  },
  {
    $project: {
        "feature_things.feature_keys": 0,
        "feature_things.features_array": 0
    } 
  },
 ] )
```

Comment: I suggest use `$addFields` as 2nd stage (instead of a `$project`), and then add a _4th stage_ to the pipeline to _exclude_ `feature_things.feature_keys` and `feature_things.features_array` to complete the query.

Comment: Thanks. I like your suggested refinements. There is a slight challenge with the 4th stage in determine when to remove `feature_things.feature_keys` seeing that it's used for grouping the documents If you make a suggested edit to the answer with this improvements, I'll approve.

Comment: I added the query with refinements. Thanks.